# google app script consumer with google appEngine Provider (Oauth)

Tags: google-app-engine, oauth-2.0, google-apps-script

I could get an Oauth conexion between GAS and GAE.

I built a Google Gadget which needs some data from my datastore application, it has 3 end points to finally get an access token.

> http//[myapp].appspot.com/_ah/OAuthGetRequestToken
>
> http//[myapp].appspot.com/_ah/OAuthAuthorizeToken
>
> http//[myapp].appspot.com/_ah/OAuthGetAccessToken

In GAS side i have the tipical function to get an access token.

```
function oauthTokenFetch(){  

var oAuthConfig = UrlFetchApp.addOAuthService("myAppName");  
oAuthConfig.setAccessTokenUrl("https://<myApp>appspot.com/_ah/OAuthGetAccessToken");  
oAuthConfig.setRequestTokenUrl("https://<myApp>.appspot.com/_ah/OAuthGetRequestToken");  
oAuthConfig.setAuthorizationUrl("https://<myApp>.appspot.com/_ah/OAuthAuthorizeToken"); 
oAuthConfig.setConsumerKey("<myApp>.appspot.com");  
oAuthConfig.setConsumerSecret("myConsumerSecret");  


var requestData = {  
    "method": "GET",  
    "oAuthServiceName": "myAppName",  
    "oAuthUseToken": "always"  
};  
try {        
  var response2=UrlFetchApp.fetch("http://<myApp>.appspot.com/test/oauth",requestData);  
  Logger.log(response2.getResponseCode());  
}catch(exception){  
  Logger.log(exception);      
}
```

If i revoked the access token on google accounts, it isn't able for getting another one, the popup which grants the authorization don't appears ... i have to copy the google gadget and do the authorization again.

Somebody have a Solution?

Comment: You shouldn't pass the secret in a javascript file, everybody in the world will have access to it.

Answer (score 0):

There currently isn't a method to allow you to revoke or remove an OAuth token in a script. It looks like you already filed a [bug/feature request](http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=1531) on the topic, and we'll follow up there.